# do I need partition this table?

Tags: php, mysql

my mysql table will have 50 000 rows max (blogs content, title, date, user... 14 columns total).

Do I need to partition that table ?

If yes - is it possible to create horizontal partitions regarding to value in a varchar column (column `status` values `active` / `archive` / `review` ... 5 different values).

So each partition is with different values in `status` column.

Any suggestion.

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`art` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_croatian_ci NOT NULL,
`img` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_croatian_ci NOT NULL,
`vid` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_croatian_ci NOT NULL,
`title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_croatian_ci NOT NULL,
`subtitle` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_croatian_ci NOT NULL,
`story` longtext COLLATE utf8_croatian_ci NOT NULL,
`tags` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_croatian_ci NOT NULL,
`status` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_croatian_ci NOT NULL,
`user` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_croatian_ci NOT NULL,
`pos` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_croatian_ci NOT NULL,
`titlex` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_croatian_ci NOT NULL,
`inde` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_croatian_ci;
```

Comment: 50k rows? That is nothing! But you need to define indexes on the columns you filter in your queries.

Comment: Just google *mysql indexes*

Comment: @juergend, is there any rows count after which partitioning is recommended, pls?

Comment: You don't need partitioning for lousy 50k rows! Ask again when you have 100 million rows.

Comment: Your `id` is not `AUTO_INCREMENT`?

Comment: @juergend but sometimes they say when you have duplicates its better to split your tables for normalisation.

Comment: @Noob "partitioning" does not usually refer to normalization

Comment: Whaaaat?! You don't partion to normalize your data. You should really take a SQL tutorial.

Comment: @puerto I would be more worried about a 50k row table consisting of little more than  a bunch of varchar and text fields than I would the partitioning of such a table....especially when one named `tags` outright suggests the "delimited values in a field" mistake.